# Different image rendering in Chrome/Edge and Firefox

Tags: html, css, doctype

I'm doing a website for a homework and I'm having trouble with rendering an image. It looks as intended on Chrome and Edge browsers, but on Firefox it looks displaced.

This is the page on Chrome/Edge: [Chrome/Edge Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDBey.png)

And this is a screenshot of the same page on Firefox: [Firefox image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbBD2.png)

I can't seem to understand why are they different?

```css
/* STRUTTURA BASE PER TUTTI GLI HTML */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Advent Pro');
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    font - size: 10 px;
    background - color: #ABCDEF;
}

body {
    font - family: 'Advent Pro';
}

div.all {
    position: relative;
    width: 70 % ;
    min - width: 800 px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/* CAMERA.html */

div.immDx {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin - top: 6 % ;
    font - size: 170 % ;
}

img.imgDx {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    float: right;
    height: 60 % ;

}

span.nameDx {
    position: relative;
    margin - left: 20 % ;
}

span.descDx {
    position: relative;
    margin - left: 20 % ;
    text - decoration: underline;
}

span.listaDx {
    position: relative;
    margin - left: 40 % ;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> QM-D_2_CAMERA </title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Advent Pro"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
        <div class="all">
            <div class="immDx">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YZe0gad.jpg" class="imgDx"/>
                <span class="nameDx"> HEMNES no. 202.004.56 </span> <BR/> <BR/>
                <span class="descDx"> DESCRIZIONE DEL PRODOTTO</span> <BR/> <BR/>
                <span class="nameDx"> Parti principali/ Ripiano: </span><BR/>
                <span class="listaDx"> Pino massiccio</span><BR/>
                <span class="listaDx"> Mordente</span><BR/>
                <span class="listaDx"> Vernice acrilica trasparente</span><BR/>
                <span class="nameDx"> Lati del cassetto/Parte posteriore: </span><BR/>
                <span class="listaDx"> Pino massiccio</span><BR/>
                <span class="nameDx"> Base del cassetto: </span><BR/>
                <span class="listaDx">Fibra di legno</span><BR/>
                <span class="listaDx">Lamina</span><BR/>
                <span class="descDx"> MISURE DEL PRODOTTO</span> <BR/> <BR/>
                <span class="nameDx"> Larghezza: 46 cm </span><BR/>
                <span class="nameDx"> Profondità: 35 cm </span><BR/>
                <span class="nameDx"> Altezza: 70 cm </span><BR/>
                <span class="nameDx"> Profondità cassetto (interna): 23 cm </span><BR/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem in Chrome or Firefox so there must be more going on than in the markup you show.

Comment: I update the code, the text is not perfect in Chrome, but now you can see the image problem

Comment: I still see no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Man, I created two files and put my code in. I see the blank image rectangle perfect in Chrome and on the right border in Firefox...

Comment: @GabrieleZanatta can you improve your question by adding it as code snippet and also using an absolute path for the image so we can get a preview of the issue?

Comment: @GoranStoyanov Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue here!

The problem is that you are missing the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration of your HTML code.

> The  declaration must be the very first thing in your HTML document, before the  tag.
>   The  declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.

In your case you should use the HTML5 declaration which is:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Adding it at the beginning of the document should solve this annoying problem.

Fun fact is that Stackoverflow's code snippet feature adds it by default and that's why some of the users did not notice the different rendering in Chrome and Firefox!

Comment: Now the image doesn't resize when i change the height on css. Do you now  why?

Comment: @GabrieleZanatta You have to add in your css:

`width:100%; height:100%;` to `body`,

`height: 100%;` to `div.all`

and `height: 100%;` to `div.immDx`